# How to find the terms of the continued fraction representation for $e^\pi$

Tags: continued-fractions

The question is  -  Find the first ten terms of the continued fraction representation for $e^ \pi $

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=continued+fraction+for+e%5Epi

Comment: @vadim123 how does wolfram do it? Is there an algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm:

Set $r_0$ to be your desired real number, in this case $\displaystyle e^\pi$.

Now, for $i=0,1,2,3,\ldots$, do the following steps:

Set $c_i=\lfloor r_i\rfloor$. This is the [floor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) function.
Set $r_{i+1}=\frac{1}{r_i-c_i}$.

Your desired continued fraction is now $[c_0;c_1,c_2,c_3,\ldots]$.